# Show Stream data in continuous manner in the HTML angular 16

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, stream

I am working on a stream api, and I receive as `'Content-Type': 'text/event-stream'`

Here is my stream.service.ts

```
connectToSse(): Observable<any> {
    return new Observable((observer) => {
      this.eventSource = new EventSource(`${this.url}/getStreamingData`);
      this.eventSource.onmessage = (event) => {
        // code to manipulate string data to convert it into [object, object] so that once HTML component receives, it can be shown in browser immediately

          observer.next(ArrayObj)
      };

      this.eventSource.onerror = (error) => {
        observer.error(error);
        this.closeConnection();
      };
    });
  }
```

html.component.ts

```
getStreamData() {
    this.sseSubscription = this._stream.connectToSse().subscribe(
      (event: any) => {
            // I am able to receive newly parsed array object here one by one(or maybe in pair of 2/3 sometimes depending on the chunk sent from server) as array object
          this.accumulatedData$ = of(event);
      },
      (error: any) => {
        console.error('SSE error:', error);
      }
    );
  }
```

HTML TEMPLATE

```
<div class="json-container">
  <div *ngFor="let row of accumulatedData$ | async;">    
    <ng-container *ngFor="let item of row | keyvalue">
      <div class="">
        {{item.key}} || {{item.value}}
      </div>
    </ng-container>
    <hr />
  </div>
</div>
```

I am able to display data in my HTML once all the array objects are received. But I am facing an issue here...

**Current code scenario** -

1. If I try to display the HTML with the above exact code, Only last received array objects are displayed post all the data is received and If I try to push the objects one by one using one more variable...It do display all the objects post all the data/stream is loaded

**Issue** -
I want to display the data in the browser as soon as it is received inside component.ts file and right now I am unable to do that.I have used ngZone, detectionStrategies, other observables methods as well but it doesn't make any difference to the current code scenario

Comment: If you had a stackblitz demo it would be a lot easier to help.

Comment: I don't know what `accumulatedData$` is, but I assume you should use `this.accumulatedData$.next(event);`.

Comment: I think you need to implement pipe scan on observable for adding in your array the new values.

Comment: public accumulatedData$: Observable<any[]> | undefined;

The api I am using for receiving stream data is a bit protected. So, I won't be able to create immediate stackblitz code. However, Give me some time, may be I can use setInterval and use it to create stream effect.

I have already used scan but unable to show continuous data on HTML/browser like chatGPT...Maybe I have to re-examine my all code practices carefully

Comment: Quick update - Scan do work on intervals. However, When you integrate with an api it do not work

Answer (score 1):

I think you need an accumuletor operator like `scan` (you can see documentation [hear](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/scan))

this is an example from a documentation

```
// RxJS v6+
import { of } from 'rxjs';
import { scan } from 'rxjs/operators';

const source = of(1, 2, 3);
// basic scan example, sum over time starting with zero
const example = source.pipe(scan((acc, curr) => acc + curr, 0));
// log accumulated values
// output: 1,3,6
const subscribe = example.subscribe(val => console.log(val));
```

you can add in your xxx function

```
connectToSse(): Observable<any> {
    return new Observable((observer) => {
      this.eventSource = new EventSource(`${this.url}/getStreamingData`);
      this.eventSource.onmessage = (event) => {
        // code to manipulate string data to convert it into [object, object] so that once HTML component receives, it can be shown in browser immediately

          observer.next(ArrayObj)
      };

      this.eventSource.onerror = (error) => {
        observer.error(error);
        this.closeConnection();
      };
    })
    .pipe(
        scan((acc, curr) => { your implementation })
    );
  }
```

Comment: I did tried scan as well which I forgot to mention it in my question and it had no effect in solving my problem. Instead it made it a bit worse and maybe I have to check all my code practices once again

Comment: Quick update - Scan do work on intervals. However, When you integrate with an api it do not work

Comment: Of youn create and array empty and inserti the value on tap?